# Migration from external db of Magento 1.X to Magento 2.X

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool

can we use M1 db different it was earlier means suppose we migration m1_db.sql of a site in m2 but now we have another external db m1_db_1.sql different site's db and import this also into M2 will be any issue during migration only products,customers and orders entities.

Comment: are you asking about delta migration Or fresh migration ?

Comment: I am asking for fresh migration for another external db of M1.